# Theano Test File Will Not Compile

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, cuda, theano

I have been trying to install Theano for windows 7 64 bit machine based off of the tutorial found on the website [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#visual-studio-and-cuda). I have gotten almost everything to work but after installing CUDA 5.5 and then continuing to on verifying the programs with these commands:

"Please do so, and verify that the following programs are found:

1. where gcc
2. where gendef
3. where cl
4. where nvcc"

The first three work fine but the last one returns "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)." I am not sure why because I installed CUDA and nvcc should be found. This is causing a larger problem because when I try to run this test file:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import theano
A = np.random.rand(1000,10000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
B = np.random.rand(10000,1000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
np_start = time.time()
AB = A.dot(B)
np_end = time.time()
X,Y = theano.tensor.matrices('XY')
mf = theano.function([X,Y],X.dot(Y))
t_start = time.time()
tAB = mf(A,B)
t_end = time.time()
print "NP time: %f[s], theano time: %f[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)" %(np_end-np_start, t_end-t_start)
print "Result difference: %f" % (np.abs(AB-tAB).max(), )
```

Eclipsed throws the error at the fourth line under config saying "Undefined variable from import: config". Then when I run it anyways the error in the console is "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'"

Any suggestions or advice on any of this is much appreciated.

Comment: It seems likely that `nvcc` is not in any of the paths being searched.  You may want to locate `nvcc.exe` on your system, and then add the path to it to your %PATH% environment variable, either permanently (via Windows computer properties...) or in the env.bat file (in the set PATH=... line).  I'm not sure that has any bearing on the import config issue, but it may.

Comment: That worked in solving my "where nvcc" issue. It can find that now so that thank you for that. It did not fix my AttritbuteError problem in the test file like I thought it would though. Not sure what the problem is now.

Comment: How was Theano installed? Are you trying to run the test file in the Theano src directory? Do you have a Python package of your own in the path called `theano` that is shadowing (i.e. hiding) the real theano package?

Comment: I actually just ended up installing it on a VM using Ubuntu. Much easier. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem was fixed in the comments on the question.

For the import, I suggest that you uninstall Theano. Do this many times to make sure you remove all version. Depending how you installed python, it could have installed an old version of Theano at the same time.

Then install Theano development version.

Then it can't find theano.config, most of the time is because there is problem in the installation or you use an old version that had problems related to Windows.